# What does it means (concretly) that a VAE encode inputs as distribution?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder, vae

From [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-variational-autoencoders-vaes-f70510919f73) post we can read that VAEs encode inputs as distributions instead of simple points ?

What does it mean concretely ? If the encoder consists of the weights between the input image and the latent space (bottleneck layer), where is the "probability distribution" in all that ?

Thank you

Comment: Roughly the VAE weights ([referred to as $\theta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_autoencoder)) parametrise a space which represents a distribution. **The distribution is the overall space encoded by the VAE, it is not the weights of its layers**

Comment: @NikosM. in the VAE architecture, the input image is fed into two parallel neural networks,  one that encode the mean of the image, and one that encodes the variance, so can we say that each of these networks only output one number ? (the mean and the variance respectively)

Comment: I am not aware of such architecture, can you provide a link? What I know is that the training is based on 2 networks one encodes and the other decodes, so that error is minimum. Then one part of the network is used as VAE.